# Polymer dom-module show nothing

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer-1.0

i am new to polymer. So i just follow the tutorial. And i don't know why details in  doesn't show on the screen.

this is the code from the net:
(index)
     
     
     
        First poly

```
<body class:"vertical layout" style="background-color: #dddddd;">
    <script src="components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="components/polymer/polymer.html">

        <paper-header-panel>              
            <link rel="import" href="components/paper-material/paper-material.html">
            <paper-material style="background: #ADADAD">
                <link rel="import" href="first.html">
                <first>
                </first>

            </paper-material>
        </paper-header-panel>
</body>
</html>
```

(first)

```
<dom-module id="first">
    <template>
       <style>
          div { color: red }
       </style>
       <div>Hello World</div> 
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer ({ is : "first" }); 
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 2):

From the Polymer docs [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html)

> By specification, the custom element’s name **must contain a dash (-).**

Therefore your elements name `first` is invalid. Try renaming to `my-element`. I would also move your `script` and element imports into the `<head>` of the project.

Comment: This is a life saver tip for a polymer beginner. Thanks a lot!